# Django: How can I make Form Wizard take in a request object when it creates the forms?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, request, django-formwizard

How can I make it so that when Django's Form Tool's Wizard creates my forms, it also gives `request` object as a parameter? The main reason why I'm using Form Tool is to have a multi-page form. Right now to "normally" create my `AnswerForm` without the Wizard, it looks like

```
form = AnswerForm(request=request)
```

I'm taking in `request` because inside the form, I want to keep track of a key called `'question'` in `request.session`. (The purpose of this key is to make sure that I can keep track of the `Question` model instance that is associated with the `Answer` instance that I'm trying to create through this form. I'm actually not sure if this is a good way to do this. Tips?) Anyway, right now I'm getting an error that seems to mean that somewhere in my `ReviewWizard`, `request` is not a parameter when the `AnswerForm` is created. I've read about how `instance_dict` can be used in the Wizard's `as_view()` in `urls.py`, but I don't think it would help in this case since the `request` object isn't available in `urls.py`. Can anyone help me with this? Or do you know of a better approach to do what I'm trying to do in general? Thanks for your help!!

(Ultimately the reason why I'm trying to keep track of `Questions` with `Answers` through `request.session` is because I think that when the first form a person sees shows up, it's a different instance from the form that gets POSTed. Since my `setup()` gets a random `Question`, it will probably not match up with the `Question` of the POSTed form, but maybe there's a better approach to all of this?? )

Line from `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^review_form/', ReviewWizard.as_view([AnswerForm, AnswerForm]), name='review_form'),
```

This is my form:

```
class AnswerForm(forms.Form):
    answer = forms.CharField(required=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request')
        self.question = None
        self.setup()
        super(AnswerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['answer'].label = self.question.question

    def setup(self):
        if "question" in self.request.session:
            self.question = Question.objects.get(id=self.request.session["question"])
        else:
            self.question = get_random_question()
            self.request.session["question"] = self.question.id

    def save(self):
        del self.request.session["question"]
        Answer.objects.create(
            question=self.question,
            author=self.request.user,
            answer=self.cleaned_data['answer']
        )
```

This is my Wizard Class in `views.py` (I copied it from elsewhere):

```
def process_form_data(form_list):
    form_data = [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list]

    print form_data[0]
    print form_data[1]

    return form_data
class ReviewWizard(SessionWizardView):
    template_name = "review_form.html"

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        form_data = process_form_data(form_list)

        return render("done.html", {"form_data": form_data})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `get_form_kwargs` method from SessionWizardView to add your request into form kwargs.

```
def process_form_data(form_list):
    form_data = [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list]

    print form_data[0]
    print form_data[1]

    return form_data
class ReviewWizard(SessionWizardView):
    template_name = "review_form.html"

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        form_data = process_form_data(form_list)

        return render("done.html", {"form_data": form_data})

    def get_form_kwargs(self, step):
        kwargs = super(ReviewWizard, self).get_form_kwargs(step)
        kwargs['request'] = self.request
        return kwargs
```

Comment: Ah, this seems to have done the trick. Thanks!! On a side note, what do you think about my overall approach. Is there a better way to do this?